# wget command not found while putting inside bash script

Tags: bash, path, wget

I have written following bash script:

```
 #!/bin/sh

echo "Number of command line arguments : $#"
if [ $# == 0 ]; then
   echo "Your command line contains no arguments"
   declare -a arr=("xx.xx.xx.xx" "yy.yy.yy.yy")
else
   declare -a arr=($1)
fi


for i in "${arr[@]}"
do
   URL="https://"$i":8443"
   echo "URL is $URL"
   wget --no-check-certificate $URL/heapdump
done
```

It keeps failing with line 16: wget: command not found

I have found some related posts but could not figure out how to fix this. Thanks.

Comment: what output when you run `wget` in server ?

Comment: Btw.: sh is usally not bash.

Comment: For testing, insert `which wget` into your script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you type a command (which is is not an internal command or a shell function), bash searches the directories mentioned in the variable `PATH` for a file of this name (`wget` in your case), which has the executable bit set for the user running the script. In your case, no suitable `wget` has been found.

Since it is unlikely that you do have a `wget` in your PATH without x-bit set, the most likely cause is that the PATH is lacking the directory where your wget lives.

You have two options: Extend the PATH, or explicitly prefix the `wget` line in your script with the correct path, i.e.

```
/here/is/my/wget --no-check-certificate $URL/heapdump
```

Answer (score 1):

For getting path of executable files such as wget please use ‘which’ cmd:

```
which wget
```

Output:

```
/full/path/wget
```